# no bean for AuthenticationManagerBuilder

Tags: spring, unit-testing, security, junit, spring-security-oauth2

I was following some tutorial for basic authentication using OAuth2. Whole thing works, but tests no. There are even simple class unit tests not working. I've got:

```
No qualifying bean of type org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder'.
```

AuthorizationServerConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
@Autowired
public AuthorizationServerConfig(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder){
    this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
}

@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients.inMemory().withClient("clientId")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials", "password")
            .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT","ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT").scopes("read","write","trust")
            .resourceIds("oauth2-resource").accessTokenValiditySeconds(3600).secret("secret");
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
    security.checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
}
}
```

UserDetails implementation:

```
public class CustomUserDetails implements UserDetails {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -3962786160780714576L;
private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities;
private String password;
private String username;
private boolean enabled;

public CustomUserDetails(User user) {
    this.username = user.getUsername();
    this.password = user.getPassword();
    this.authorities = translate(user.getRoles());
    this.enabled = user.getEnabled();
}

private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> translate(List<Role> roles) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
    roles.stream().forEach(x -> authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(x.getName())));
    return authorities;
}

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return authorities;
}

@Override
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return enabled;
}
}
```

ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.headers().frameOptions().disable().and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/","/home","/register","/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/dev/hello-world").authenticated();
}
}


@SpringBootApplication
public class LimeApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LimeApplication.class, args);
    }
```

Main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SomeApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SomeApplication.class, args);
    }

@Autowired
public void authenticationManager(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder, IUserDAO dao, PasswordEncoder encoder) throws Exception {
    builder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService(dao)).passwordEncoder(encoder);
}


private UserDetailsService userDetailsService(final IUserDAO dao) {
    return username -> new CustomUserDetails(dao.findByUsername(username));
}

}
```

application.yml

```
security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      filter-order: 3
```

I was looking and I was trying to disable authentication in `test/resources/application.yml` by

```
security:
  basic:
    enabled: false
```

But this does not work. I cannot find any answer how to correct or mock this. Can anyone help me? Does anyone know how to mock it? Or get this bean in tests?

Edit:
Tests are running with `@DataJpaTest @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` annotations